# Arduino protyping simulation software

Tags: arduino, prototyping, simulation

Is there any (preferably open source, preferably python; *only linux*) software for microcontroller board prototyping simulation? I'm an EE and we used spice in classes to simulate circuit level stuff. Is there anything like that?

Is there a specific term for what this would be called? Just simulation software?

*Also*: I crossposted this on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528990/arduino-mcb-protyping-simulation-software) because I totally forgot this place existed. Hope that's ok.

Comment: speaking as an old-time unix programmer, you will probably find a lot more embedded programming tools in the windows world.  Look for something that works well with WINE or with vmware.  A python-based environment would be great, though!

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for Arduino simulator, there is [virtualbreadboard.net](http://www.virtualbreadboard.net/Shop/tabid/206/Default.aspx). It can do stuff like this:
[image]

Comment: that looks similar to fritzing. http://fritzing.org/

Comment: I recommend using both linux and windows. Those restricted to one or the other miss out in great programs, and limit their program portability.

Answer (score 3):

This simulator is called as `SimulIDE` just you want to do is after prototype the circuit

---

[image]

right click on the sketch and load the .hex compiled arduino program to this sketch

---

How to use [Description Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8qj-tqhe2g)

---

Download the app [Download link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simulide/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of SimulIDE with more components and features, including PIC, AVR and Arduino simuation:

[image]

Video example: https://youtu.be/BhkgiVKw5A4

Regards.